# Excel VBA Internet explorer click button with no ID

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

new to stackoverflow, I searched on this forum and others and tried their suggestion without success before posting this. I'm new to Excel VBA and trying to automate a search on bestbuy.com using VBA. The search field works but I can't submit the search, I inspected the "button" but it has no ID.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you all!

```
> Sub AAA() 
> Set objie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
> objie.Top = 0 
> objie.Left = 0 
> objie.Width = 800 
> objie.Height = 600
> objie.AddressBar = 0 
> objie.StatusBar = 0
> objie.Toolbar = 0
> objie.Visible = True 
> 
> 
> objie.Navigate ("http://www.bestbuy.com") Do DoEvents Loop Until
> objie.ReadyState = 4
> 
>             objie.Document.getElementById("gh-search-input").Value = "bose radio"
>             objie.Document.getElementByClassName("header-search-button").Click
> Do
> Do events
> Loop Until objie.ReadyState = 4
> End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
objie.document.forms(0).submit
```

Comment: SO can be quite fast at times :-)

Comment: @QHarr Well said. +1 for that. :)